# Import data into Mathematica

Tags: import, matlab

I have one question.I have got my data xy1 from Matlab.But when I import it into Mathematica,I get result as follow

```
  XY1 = Import["xy1.mat", Path -> "D:\\Matlab\\data"]
```

[image]

My data xy1:

[image]

Sorry,I do not know how to import my data xy1.mat here.If you know,I will import it here.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Matlab, why not transform format from ".mat" to ".csv".  A MAT-file stores data in binary (not human-readable) form. You can find some information about MAT-file from this link: 
https://wenku.baidu.com/view/6d6ee6bd960590c69ec37646.html

But if you use Matlab transforn file format to "csv", then use Mathematica import data is very simple. You can use this Code:

```
Import["*.csv"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have never thought the transform format from ".mat" to ".csv" before.Maybe I do not Import  data from one software to another